# jQuery iteration HTML5 table

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have this code to iterate through and add the values to the a HTML table. Though it does it but it creates a new table for each record which is not suppose to be so. the attached file shows exactly how I want to appear. I want for each record added through the form it should be added as a record to the same table.

This is the jQuery code

```
var createStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Contacts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT, useremail TEXT)";

var selectAllStatement = "SELECT * FROM Contacts";

var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Contacts (username, useremail) VALUES (?, ?)";

var updateStatement = "UPDATE Contacts SET username = ?, useremail = ? WHERE id=?";

var deleteStatement = "DELETE FROM Contacts WHERE id=?";

var dropStatement = "DROP TABLE Contacts";

var db = openDatabase("AddressBook.db", "1.0", "Address Book", 200000);  // Open SQLite Database

var dataset;

var DataType;

 function initDatabase()  // Function Call When Page is ready.

{

    try {

        if (!window.openDatabase)  // Check browser is supported SQLite or not.

        {

            alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');

        }

        else {

            createTable();  // If supported then call Function for create table in SQLite

        }

    }

    catch (e) {

        if (e == 2) {

            // Version number mismatch. 

            console.log("Invalid database version.");

        } else {

            console.log("Unknown error " + e + ".");

        }

        return;

    }

}

function createTable()  // Function for Create Table in SQLite.

{

    db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(createStatement, [], showRecords, onError); });

}

function insertRecord() // Get value from Input and insert record . Function Call when Save/Submit Button Click..
{

        var usernametemp = $('input:text[id=username]').val();

        var useremailtemp = $('input:text[id=useremail]').val();

        db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(insertStatement, [usernametemp, useremailtemp], loadAndReset, onError); });

        //tx.executeSql(SQL Query Statement,[ Parameters ] , Sucess Result Handler Function, Error Result Handler Function );

}

function deleteRecord(id) // Get id of record . Function Call when Delete Button Click..

{

    var iddelete = id.toString();

    db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(deleteStatement, [id], showRecords, onError); alert("Deleted Sucessfully"); });

    resetForm();

}

function updateRecord() // Get id of record . Function Call when Delete Button Click..

{

    var usernameupdate = $('input:text[id=username]').val().toString();

    var useremailupdate = $('input:text[id=useremail]').val().toString();

    var useridupdate = $("#id").val();

    db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(updateStatement, [usernameupdate, useremailupdate, Number(useridupdate)], loadAndReset, onError); });

}

function dropTable() // Function Call when Drop Button Click.. Talbe will be dropped from database.

{

    db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(dropStatement, [], showRecords, onError); });

    resetForm();

    initDatabase();

}

function loadRecord(i) // Function for display records which are retrived from database.

{

    var item = dataset.item(i);

    $("#username").val((item['username']).toString());

    $("#useremail").val((item['useremail']).toString());

    $("#id").val((item['id']).toString());

}

function resetForm() // Function for reset form input values.

{

    $("#username").val("");

    $("#useremail").val("");

    $("#id").val("");

}

function loadAndReset() //Function for Load and Reset...

{

    resetForm();

    showRecords();

}

function onError(tx, error) // Function for Hendeling Error...

{

    //alert(error.message);


}

// function showRecords() // Function For Retrive data from Database Display records as list

// {

    // $("#results").html('')

    // db.transaction(function (tx) {

        // tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function (tx, result) {

            // dataset = result.rows;

            // for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {

                // item = dataset.item(i);

                // var linkeditdelete = 
                // '<table border = "2">'   
                // +'<br>'

                    // +'<tr>'
                        // +'<td>' + item['username'] + ' </td> '  
                        // +'<td>' + item['useremail'] + ' </td>'   
                        // +'<td>' + '<a href="#" onclick="loadRecord(' + i + ');">edit</a>' + '</td>'  
                        // +'<td>' + '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRecord(' + item['id'] + ');">delete</a></td>'                  

                // $("#results").append(linkeditdelete);
                // +'</tr>'

                // +'<table>';

            // }

        // });

    // });

// }

function showRecords() // Function For Retrive data from Database Display records as  list
{
$("#results").html('')
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function (tx, result) {

        dataset = result.rows;
        $("#results").append('<table border = "2">' + '<br><th>Full Nmaes</th><th>Email</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th>');
        for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {
            item = dataset.item(i);

            var linkeditdelete =

            + '<tr>' + '<td>' + item['username'] + ' </td> ' + '<td>' + item['useremail'] + ' </td>' + '<td>' + '<a href="#" onclick="loadRecord(' + i + ');">edit</a>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRecord(' + item['id'] + ');">delete</a></td>'

            $("#results").append(linkeditdelete); + '</tr>'


        }
        $("#results").append('</table>');

    });

});

}           

$(document).ready(function () // Call function when page is ready for load..

{

    $("body").fadeIn(2000); // Fade In Effect when Page Load..

    initDatabase();

    $("#submitButton").click(insertRecord);  // Register Event Listener when button click.

    $("#btnUpdate").click(updateRecord);

    $("#btnReset").click(resetForm);

    $("#btnDrop").click(dropTable);

});
```

this is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>

 <html>

<head>

    <title>Contact Form</title>

    <link rel="Stylesheet"  href="ExercisePage3StyleSheet.css"/>

    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<body>

<h1>CONTACT FORM</h1>

              <form id="mycontact">

                     <fieldset>

                           <legend>Your details</legend>

                           <ol>

                                  <li>

                                         <label for="username">Name</label>

                                         <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="First name and Last name" required autofocus pattern=" ">

                        <input type="hidden" id="id"/>

                                  </li>

                                  <li>

                                         <label for="useremail">Email</label>

                                         <input id="useremail" type="text" placeholder="example@domain.com" required pattern=" ">

                                  </li>

                                  <li>

                                         <label for="userselection">User selection</label>

                                         <select id="userselection" width = "30">
                                            <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
                                        </select>

                                  </li>

                           </ol>

                     </fieldset>

                <button id="btnReset" type=submit>Reset</button>

                     <button id="submitButton" type="submit">SAVE</button>

                <button id="btnUpdate" type=submit>UPDATE</button>

                <button id="btnDrop" type=submit>DROP</button>

              </form><br />

        <div id="results"></div>

</body>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="ExercisePage3JS.js"> </script>

</html>

<span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: small;">
```

[image: This is what I want to achieve.]

Comment: well, you open a new table each time you go through your data. Create a table once and just insert the data. Also a `<br />` has nothing to do inside a table and not inside a `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

Don't add `<table>` in your loop. Add `<table>` to `#results`

```
 function showRecords() // Function For Retrive data from Database Display records as list

        {

            $("#results").html('')

            db.transaction(function (tx) {

                tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function (tx, result) {

                    dataset = result.rows;

                    for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {

                        item = dataset.item(i);

                        var linkeditdelete = 

                            +'<tr>'
                                +'<td>' + item['username'] + ' </td> '  
                                +'<td>' + item['useremail'] + ' </td>'   
                                +'<td>' + '<a href="#" onclick="loadRecord(' + i + ');">edit</a>' + '</td>'  
                                +'<td>' + '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRecord(' + item['id'] + ');">delete</a></td>'                 


                        +'</tr>'
      $("#results").append(linkeditdelete);

                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this :

Change the element `<div id="results"></div>` to `<table id="results"></table>` in your **HTML** file.

and replace the `showRecords()` function in your **JavaScript**  by this one :

```
function showRecords() // Function For Retrive data from Database Display records as  list
{
    $("#results").html('')
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function (tx, result) {
        dataset = result.rows;
        for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {
            item = dataset.item(i);
             var linkeditdelete =  '<tr><td>' + item['username'] + ' </td><td>' + item['useremail'] + ' </td><td>' +      '<a href="#" onclick="loadRecord(' + i + ');">edit</a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRecord(' + item['id'] + ');">delete</a></td></tr>';
             $("#results").append(linkeditdelete);
        }
        });
    });
}
```

PS: I simplified the example in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afPeK/) if you want a working example.

Comment: It is still giving the same result. more info on what to do, please!